# bbpress doesn't send mail when my host has disabled php's mail() - workaround?

Tags: bbpress

I just realized my bbpress isn't sending emails. Probably for the same reason wordpress wouldn't: **mail()** is not allowed on my host.

I'm wondering if there is a simple work around for this... wordpress has some plugins which can tell it to use another route but I haven't come across anything for bbpress, yet.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

I may have spoken too soon.... I came across:

http://bbpress.org/plugins/topic/smtp-mailer-for-bbpress/